# Using Taylor series to create a sequence of intervals bracketing the value of a function.

Tags: real-analysis

So the Taylor Series is

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)\cdot(x-a)^n}{n!} $$

I would like to know under what circumstances it is possible to get an absolute error term since I want to use Taylor series to produce a series of smaller and smaller intervals bracketing the true value.

$$ f(x) \in \left( \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f^{n}(a) \cdot (x-a)^n}{n!} \right) \pm R_k(x) $$

From the Wikipedia article on Taylor's theorem I found two explicit forms for particular $R_k$.

Lagrange Form:

$$ R_k(x) = \frac{f^{(k+1)}(\xi_L) \cdot (x-a)^{(k+1)} }{(k+1)!} \; \text{with} \; \xi_L \; \text{between} \; x \; \text{and} \; a $$

Cauchy Form:

$$ R_k(x) = \frac{f^{(k+1)}(\xi_C) \cdot (x-\xi_C)^{k}(x- a)  }{(k+1)} \; \text{with} \; \xi_C \; \text{between} \; x \; \text{and} \; a $$

Does this mean that I can pick any value between $x$ and $a$ for $ \xi_L $ or $ \xi_C $ or do I have to consider all $\xi_L$ or $\xi_C$ and pick the one that produces the largest possible error term? Thanks.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder